# What is the name of combination, in error, of similar or related words? (E.g.: segueway) 

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, phrase-requests, terminology, errors

Is there a technical term for combination, in error, of similar or related words?  This question is prompted by the following malapropism or solecism, from an article by Elizabeth Montalbano in [InformationWeek](http://www.informationweek.com/news/government/info-management/231901914):

> The project also serves as a segueway into the next-generation Joint Polar Satellite System (JPSS), a program by NOAA that also will collect weather and climate data.

The writer presumably formed *segueway* by miscegenation of [segue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segue) with [Segway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segway_PT).  The problem does not seem to be a simple [typographical error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error), which "includes errors due to mechanical failure or slips of the hand or finger, but usually excludes errors of ignorance, such as spelling errors."  It also seems unlikely to be a [neologism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism).  Some processes of [word formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_formation) -- agglutination, back-formation, blending, *etc.* -- of course are in play here, but those terms don't imply error.

Comment: It's possible he was going for "segue", but didn't realize the "ue" part was pronounced "way". Words like *vague* and *vogue* could give someone the idea that the "ue" is silent.

Comment: is this a variety of eggcorn? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn

Comment: Mahnax @FumbleFingers Isn't Elizabeth normally a women's name?

Comment: Your "miscegenation" seemed like a pretty good coinage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Misjuxtaposition** is used in these situations. It's something that exists in "common use", but not the dictionary so I don't know that that would count here.

Answer (score 4):

Malaprop?

Otherwise, I would say eggcorn.

Comment: While *[eggcorn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eggcorn)* may be appropriate, *[malapropism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malapropism)* (use of an inappropriate word in place of a similar sounding one) plainly is not.

Comment: Eggcorn is exactly what you need, per jwpat